# ddrescue status is there any hope?

Tags: ddrescue

I have an external hard drive of 1Tb which stopped working. I'm trying to recover the information using ddrescue but I don't see anything been recovered.

I'm doing the copy from the external harddrive to another one, but it has been more than a week and I dont see anything saying that information is been recovering. Should I stop?. THis external harddrive has important information :(.

Is there anyhope?. IN the image it says 2 days but my laptop restarted so I continued the process from a mapfile.[image]

Also from ddrecueview:
[image]

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Testdisk is not the right tool in this situation. OP cannot even read a single byte from the disk. The partition tables and file-systems are well inaccessible.

Answer (score 1):

Abort this try. You can always resume later on, but I doubt it will help. Before you continue or try anything else, please check:

- Is the disk spinning at all?
- Does it sound okay while trying to read?

Chances are the disk has electrical or mechanical issues. I once managed do pull data from a disk only when it was reasonably cool, so I put it in the freezer.

I do not know what your drive has been through, but please be aware: Trying to use (read from) a damaged drive can make things even worse up to the point that even a commercial service provider will be unable to recover any data.

Comment: The hard drive has a light that keeps flashing so I beleive is still alive. It doesnt make any sound and If I touch it is not hot at all.

Comment: A traditional hard-disk drive vibrates and hums. No sound whatsoever probably means the drive's motor is not starting at all. You may try spinning the drive's housing right after powering it up. With really good luck, the spindle will come loose and turn. However, the drive probably tried to do that the last days, so I am afraid, it won't help.

Comment: Just to clarify this is an Toshiba USB 3.0 external hardrive.

Comment: @kiduxa An external drive gives you a couple of additional options. You can disassemble the housing and connect the drive directly to your mainboard.

Comment: Yes, disassembling it would solve the problem in case the disk is still good but the external case electronics is broken.